# Grafana error - parse error : input size too long (5491 > 5120)

Tags: grafana, grafana-loki, grafana-variable, grafana-alerts, promtail

I see the following error in our Grafana dashboard, which uses LOKI as a data source. Sometimes it shows the data, but other times it throws this error.

```
parse error : input size too long (XXX > 5120)
```

When I run the same query in Explorer, it works. What is this error, what does it mean ?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue! In my case it is related to the usage of the "All" option in the dashboard's variables.

For instance, image that we have a variable to allow the user to filter by container name and there are a lot of values for that variable.
If the user selects the option “All”, the generated query will have a filter with all possible values.

Something like:

`count_over_time({container_name=~"name1|name2|name3|...|nameX"} [$__range]})`

Eventually, we hit the query length limit (5120 chars).

[image: Grafana loki query translation example]

**The solution:**
In the dashboard variavels definiton, there is the option **"Custom all value"**.

I have set that with: **.+**

So, when we select the value "All", the generated query become:

`count_over_time({container_name=~".+"} [$__range]})`